# Switching over to another SQL instance

Tags: installation, migration, azure, azuresql

Assume a fully fledged 8.5 CMS+DXA deployment, backed by an Azure SQL managed instance. We need to switch over to another instance, syncing over the original DBs -> How complex is the change to be done in the config files&tables in order to avoid re-installment? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For CD side it is easier, all DB related info is located in `cd_storage_conf` and `deployer-conf` files. After update just restart microservices.

For CM side it is a little trickier since DB related info is encrypted using Tridion Rsa key.

CM DB info is located in `%TRIDION_HOME%\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config`

Topology Manager DB info is located in `%TRIDION_HOME%\TopologyManager\web\Web.config`

Translation Manager DB info is located in `%TRIDION_HOME%\config\TranslationManager.xml`

I'm not sure if any other CM add-on uses its own database.

You will need to first decrypt database part of those config files, update values, encrypt them again and restart CM server.

Keep copies of old config files just in case and test this on Dev environment first.

You can use the following links as guidelines for updating CM config files:

- https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000008073
- https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=000005881

Answer (score 2):

Besides Stefan's answer which covers all the scenarios, if you need to replace just the CM database, you can do it using the SDL Console (MMC snapin) so you don't have to tamper with config files.

[image]